# Pandas DataFrame - Filter rows according to substring

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's assume I've created a data frame, and I want to filter all rows in which the value in column C is not a substring of the value in column B.

For example -

```
Column A         Column B
string           str
another          arr
nope             eee
```

As you can see, none of the values in column B exists in column A, however the string 'str' is a substring of 'string' - I would like to filter these lines and remain only with lines 2 and 3.

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: do you only want the operation to be per row, or would you want to drop for example a 4th row that, in Column A you have "asd**str**asd" and in Column B you have "fgh", which contains str from first row but not "fgh" from current row? Would you want to keep that?

Comment: No, it needs to be "per row", as you can assume the data is sorted

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
mask = df[["Column A", "Column B"]].apply(lambda x: x["Column B"] in x["Column A"], axis=1)
res = df[mask]
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
0     True
1    False
2    False
dtype: bool
```